# How to grab element you are hovering over?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you grab the element you are currently hovering over using **pure** Javascript, no jQuery?

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

### JavaScript

```
(function() {

    var item = document.querySelector('li');

    function randomColor() {
        return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
    }

    item.onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    };

    item.onmouseleave = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    };

}());
```

The problem is that it only changes the color on one of the elements, but not the other 2 when hovering over.

**Solution thanks to RUJordan**

```
(function() {

    var box = document.querySelectorAll('li');

    function randomColor() {
        return '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= box.length; i++) {

        box[i].onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
        };  

        box[i].onmouseleave = function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
        };

    }

}());
```

Comment: Why not just grab the `ul`?

Comment: @zsaat14 how would that help?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I thought you were trying to change all three li's at once.  I put it in a jsfiddle and saw your issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`querySelector` only returns the first index of the array of elements you would get back from that method.

To get all `li`, use `querySelectorAll("li")` and loop through the elements node list (array like) to add `eventListeners` to them.

Comment: nice one, It was easy, I can't believe I didn't notice it.

Comment: I posted it on my question edit for future reference

Answer (score 1):

I don't use jquery.  This function returns the element that triggered the event.

```
function eventTarget(e) {
    return (e && e.target ? e.target : event.srcElement);
}
```

Does that help?  e is the event object, the event.srcElement is for internet explorer compatibility.